Are odd forms (twisted forms) invariant (geometric) objects
Are de Rham odd differential forms invariant with respect to the choice of basis or not?
de Rham: "If the manifold $V$ is oriented, that is, if it is orientable and if we have chosen an orientation $\epsilon$, we may associate with each odd form $\alpha$ an even form $\epsilon\alpha$. Therefore, in the case of an orientable manifold, we are able to eliminate the use of odd forms by fixing an orientation on $V$. But for non-orientable manifolds, this concept is in fact useful and natural." Differentiable Manifolds Forms, Currents, Harmonic Forms (1984) p.20.
If $\tilde \alpha=\epsilon \alpha$ holds, where I denoted $\tilde\alpha$ odd form, $\tilde\alpha$ is not an invariant object because $\alpha$ is invariant and $\epsilon$ changes due to the choice of base. I thought that whether the form is even or odd is only about representation.
In contrast, Burke: "Twisted tensors do transform with a sign change under inversion of coordinates, and that may seem unnatural. But the fact is that under such an inversion a twisted tensor does not itself change, and its coordinate representation changes sign only to follow the changing coordinates." Applied differential geometry (1985). page 183.
According to which they are invariant.
Further:
Can we say that twisted forms are odd forms with outer orientation?
De Rham does not talk about the orientation of even forms, does this mean that he assumes the orientation of the entire space (according to Burke's inner orientation)?
And finally:
"The definitions of the exterior product and of the differential, together with formulas (2) and (3) of § 4, apply as well to odd forms as to even forms. We note that the differential $d\alpha$ of $\ alpha$ has the same parity as $\alpha$, and that the product of two forms of the same parity is an even form while the product of two forms of different parity is an odd form." Differentiable Manifolds Forms, Currents, Harmonic Forms (1984) p.20.
Is this concept somehow related to parity checking using reflection? After all, the exterior derivative increases the degree of the form and thus changes the parity or not?
Add:
consider the $2$-form in $\Lambda_2(E_3)$ and the parity transformation represented by the matrix $T=\text{diag}(-1,1,1)$, orientation $\epsilon=\text{sgn}\Big(\ det\big(T\big)\Big)$, then
if we only add over the cyclically ordered set :$$\omega^{\text{even}}=\omega_{ij}\mathrm dx^i\wedge \mathrm dx^j=T_i^kT_j^l\omega_{kl}\,\widetilde{\mathrm dx^i}\wedge \widetilde{\mathrm dx^j}
=\omega_{23}\widetilde{\mathrm dx^2}\wedge \widetilde{\mathrm dx^3}
-\omega_{31}\widetilde{\mathrm dx^3}\wedge \widetilde{\mathrm dx^1}
-\omega_{12}\widetilde{\mathrm dx^1}\wedge \widetilde{\mathrm dx^2}$$
$$\omega^{\text{odd}}=\omega^\prime_{ij}\mathrm dx^i\wedge \mathrm dx^j=\text{sgn}\Big(\det\big(T\big )\Big)T_i^kT_j^l\omega^\prime_{kl}\widetilde{\mathrm dx^i}\wedge \widetilde{\mathrm dx^j}
=-\omega^\prime_{23}\widetilde{\mathrm dx^2}^i\wedge \widetilde{\mathrm dx^3}
+\omega^\prime_{31}\widetilde{\mathrm dx^3}\wedge \widetilde{\mathrm dx^1}
+\omega^\prime_{12}\widetilde{\mathrm dx^1}\wedge \widetilde{\mathrm dx^2}.$$
$$\Longrightarrow \omega_{\text{even}}=\epsilon\omega_{\text{odd}}=-\omega_{\text{odd}},\qquad
\omega_{ij}=\epsilon\omega^\prime_{ij}=-\omega^\prime_{ij}$$
Which is consistent with both de Rham and Burke.
Do I understand correctly that the $\epsilon$ orientation reverses the parity, then the odd $2$- form does not have an odd parity, but an even parity, and can it then be used to represent polar vectors?

What is the definition of an orientation in deRham? I wonder what is that $\epsilon \alpha$.

@ArcticChar DeRham says an orientation is a continuous odd scalar field $\epsilon$ with $\epsilon^2=1$. In modern language, this amounts — of course — to the existence of a volume form.
